# MFC CFormView OnKeyDown event not triggered

Tags: c++, events, mfc, message

I have a CFormView and I have some controls on it. I have implemented an OnKeyDown event on my CFormView. Everything is good, except my event is never triggered because the focus is on a combo box in my CFormView. I don't want the combo box to receive the event. I want the CFormView to receive it. So I implemented PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg) and it removes the event from the combo box but it never gives it to the CFormView. Here is the code:

```
BOOL CfinalprojView::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg) { 
if( pMsg->message == WM_KEYDOWN ) {
    SendMessage( WM_COMMAND, MAKEWPARAM( IDD_FINALPROJ_FORM, BN_CLICKED ), ( LPARAM )0 );
    return TRUE; 
} else if( pMsg->message == WM_KEYUP ) {
    return TRUE; 
} else {
    return CFormView::PreTranslateMessage( pMsg );
}}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance,

Corneliu

Comment: Why don't you want the combo box to handle the event?

Comment: Because I would like to paint stuff on the CFormView when the user hits the keys.

Comment: If the combo box is a child control of the form, what is stopping you from executing a parent (form) method to do the painting?

Comment: The combo box or any other component on my CFormView should have nothing to do with the stuff that is specific to the CFormView. I simply want my CFormView to receive an event that would paint it. If I implement the form painting in the combo box, then I have to implement that in every single control because I don't know which control will have the focus.

Comment: Also, I am new to MFC, I don't know how to get a handle on the parent. But I think the whole design would be horrible. It's the last thing I would do.

Comment: I just realized that BN_CLICKED should not be there. I need the key event equivalent of that clicked event constant, but I can't find it.

Comment: Instead of this line: `SendMessage( WM_COMMAND, MAKEWPARAM( IDD_FINALPROJ_FORM, BN_CLICKED ), ( LPARAM )0 );` out the code from your OnKeyDown method in the PreTranslateMessage(), or even call OnKeyDown() from PreTranslateMessage(). What's the problem?

Comment: Yes, I thought about that and it's not a bad idea but I don't know how to find out which key has been pressed. You see, the nice thing about OnKeyDown() is that it receives a UINT nChar parameter.

Comment: Another idea I am exploring is to put some buttons on the interface and use key mnemonics to programmatically press those buttons. I don't know if this is even possible.

Comment: Your pMsg->wParam will contain the key:    `if(pMsg->wParam == VK_DELETE)    { // do something }`

Comment: Thank you, cha. This is actually a very good solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, it seems that there is no way to forward the key events to the CFormView. Instead, one can catch the events in PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg) and check the key that was pressed like this:

```
BOOL CfinalprojView::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg) {
    if( pMsg->message == WM_KEYDOWN ) {
        if( pMsg->wParam == VK_DELETE ) {
            ...
        }
        return TRUE; 
    }
    else if( pMsg->message == WM_KEYUP )
        return TRUE; 
    else
        return CFormView::PreTranslateMessage( pMsg );
}
```